# How to prevent python extension in vscode to automatically insert new characters except space?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Only `python(v2020.6.91350)` and `material icon theme` extensions are enabled,
this is my code before saving:

```
flipkart_modified_url = flipkart_base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode({"q": search_item})
```

after saving the file my line changes to:

```
flipkart_modified_url = flipkart_base_url + \
urllib.parse.urlencode({"q": search_item})
```

why is the `\` automatically inserted into the code? and i dont understand how does the code still work with the wrong syntax, I dont want to disable the extension, is there any way to actually prevent this from happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'\' -> [This called Explicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining): Two or more physical lines may be joined into logical lines using backslash characters (\).

It was applied by the formatting you provided. If you did not set it, it defaults to 'autopep8', you can find this setting in 'defaultSettings.json', it was set by 'Python' extension. You can look in the Output panel -> Python channel to see how the 'Python' extension format your code. And of course, you need to install 'autopep8' package.

If you want to change the behavior of autopep8, not to truncate the code to lines, you can add this to settings.json file:
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
"--max-line-length",
"120",
],
And you can refer to [autopep8 docs](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the theme changes your settings to automatic formatting when saving. I recommend you to download other themes like **VSCode Icons**. If you insist using this theme, follow steps below to turn off the automatic formatting (Risk: you will have to manually format your codes by **Alt+Shift+F**):

1. Check your defalut settings(Ctrl+Shif+P, Preferences: Open Default Settings (Json))
2. Search(Ctrl+F) **editor.formatOnSave** to see if it is **"editor.formatOnType": true**. if it is, follow steps bellow:

- Ctrl+Shif+P, Preferences: Open User Settings (Json)
- Add this line:

  "editor.formatOnSave": false

  **Notice**: don't forget to add '**,**' at the end of the previous line. [Edit settings like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjTxf.png)

3. Ctrl+S to save the json file and check if the problem is solved

Comment: i want the format on save to add spaces new lines etc but i dont know why the new `/` character is being added

Comment: Because `flipkart_modified_url = flipkart_base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode({"q": search_item})` is too long, it is formatted into two lines.   "\" is used to break the long codes, because if you press `ENTER` directly to make it two lines, it will cause an syntax error.